# Bootstrap tooltip is switching width on hover

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have a specific problem with my angular web-application. I'm viewing a matrix in my application with data in it. When I hover over my data in this matrix it will show some basic information about the object. anyway: everytime when I hover over it with my cursor, it changes the width from right to left.

my HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 22px">
        <colgroup *ngFor="let y of yArray">
             <col style="width: 5%" *ngFor="let x of xArray"/>
        </colgroup>
        <tr *ngFor="let y of yArray">
            <td *ngFor="let x of xArray" [style.background]="getBackground(y+1,x+1)" 
            [tooltip]="getTooltipContent(y+1,x+1)" placement="bottom">
            {{ setBerechnung(y+1, x+1).messwert}}&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

my GetTooltipContent-Function (TS/Angular):

```
 public getTooltipContent(yKoordinate: number, xKoordinate: number)
 {
        const sensor = this.fullZoneResponse.sensorInSurface
            .filter(x => x.xKoordinate == xKoordinate && x.yKoordinate == yKoordinate);

        let zoneAssignment: IzoneAssignment[] = [];

        this.fullZonenResponse.zoneInSurface.forEach((value) => {
            zoneAssignment.push(...value.assignmentOfZone);
        });

        const sensorIsInSurface = zoneAssignment.filter(x => x.idSensor == sensor[0].id);

        if (sensorIsInSurface.length > 0) {
            this.zoneAssignment = this.fullZonenResponse.zoneInSurface.filter(x => x.id == sensorAssignment[0].idZone);
            return this.tooltipContent = this.zoneAssignment[0].description;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.tooltipContent = "";    
        }
}
```

here is a screenshot of it's normal behaviour:

[image: not hovering status]

and another one of it's bad behaviour:

[image: hovering status]

I would be very very thankful if you could help me out!

Comment: I think some css is getting distorted by tooltip. Could you add css of table and what tooltip library you are using to create ?

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy I'm using ngx-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by my own!

The problem was that my ngx-bootstrap tooltip got added to my DOM on runtime. I just added the "**container='body'**"-attribute, so the tooltip get's added on the right element.

my HTML now:

```
<tr *ngFor="let y of yArray">
      <td *ngFor="let x of xArray" container="body" [style.background]="getBackground(y+1,x+1)" [tooltip]="getTooltipContent(y+1,x+1)" placement="bottom">
          {{ setBerechnung(y+1, x+1).messwert}}&nbsp;
      </td>
</tr>
```